# Euler's method for different step sizes . How does one change the code of the algorithm to account for different values of the step size?

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, integration, numerical-methods

I have an algorithm for a numerical differential equation problem called Euler's method. Essentially Euler's method approximates a solution to differential equations. My function is working for a single step size (value `h`) but I am trying to change the code to allow me to loop over 3 different values h (by changing `h` from a single value to a list of possible values). However, the function that I wrote is not adequately looping over my values. I am new to python and previously used R. Could someone please show me how to do this properly.

My code that is working for a single value of the stepsize h is:

```
from math import exp # exponential function

dy = lambda x,y: x*y
f = lambda x: exp(x**2/2) # analytical solution function

x = 0 # Intial value X_0
xn = 2 # Final Value
y = 1 # value of y(x0)
h = 0.2 # stepsize
n = int((xn-x)/h)

print ('x \t\t y (Euler h={}) \t y (analytical)'.format(h))
print ('%f \t %f \t %f'% (x,y,f(x)))
for i in range(n):
    y += dy(x, y)*h
    x += h
    print ('%f \t %f \t %f'% (x,y,f(x)))


x        y (Euler h=0.5) y (analytical)
0.000000     1.000000    1.000000
0.500000     1.000000    1.133148
1.000000     1.250000    1.648721
1.500000     1.875000    3.080217
2.000000     3.281250    7.389056
```

I would like to change h to `h=[0.01,0.2,0.5]` and have the values to then create the plot showing the analytical solution and the Euler's method solutions at different values of the step size.

[image]

Once again I apologise if this is an easy question. I am new to programming in python and keep making some errors, below is my best attempt so far. I hadn't stored my x values into the container yet as my function was not looping over the h values. I am attempting to write a nested for loop where the outer loop, loops over the h values and stores the values and plots them as a line then iterates to the second value of h and does the same, at the end the values can then be placed on a single plot.

```
# Improved to allow plotting different values
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
from math import exp # exponential function

dy = lambda x,y: x*y
f = lambda x: exp(x**2/2) # analytical solution function
x = 0
xn = 2
y = 1
# Container for step sizes
h = [0.5,0.2,0.1]

# Container to store the x values at each stepsize
# X =np.zeros((3,))

print ('x \t\t y (Euler) \t y (analytical)')
print ('%f \t %f \t %f'% (x,y,f(x)))
for j in range(0,len(h),1):
    n = int((xn-x)/h[j])
    for i in range(n):
        y += dy(x, y)*h[j]
        x += h[j]
        print ('%f \t %f \t %f'% (x,y,f(x)))
    plt.plot(x,y)

plt.show()


x        y (Euler)   y (analytical)
0.000000     1.000000    1.000000
0.500000     1.000000    1.133148
1.000000     1.250000    1.648721
1.500000     1.875000    3.080217
2.000000     3.281250    7.389056
```

[image]

So the question is really trying to create Euler's method for different step sizes i.e. "How does one change our function to loop over a list and plot the results with matplotlib"?

Comment: You need to create a list for the x and y values and append the current values at each step. Do not forget to reset the lists when you start a new iteration for a different h.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a minor mistake and you need to store the results in a container if you want to plot them. I rewrote your code a little bit. I first give you the full code, before I discuss what was wrong with your code. Maybe you spot the errors yourself. I also added the calculation of the analytical solution and some other small enhancements that should be to your liking. So here is the code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from math import exp  # exponential function

dy = lambda x, y: x * y
f = lambda x: exp(x ** 2 / 2)  # analytical solution function
x_final = 2

# analytical solution
x_a = np.arange(0, x_final, 0.01)
y_a = np.zeros(len(x_a))
for i in range(len(x_a)):
    y_a[i] = f(x_a[i])
plt.plot(x_a, y_a, label="analytical")

# Container for step sizes
h = [0.5, 0.2, 0.1]


for j in range(len(h)):
    x = 0
    y = 1
    print("h = " + str(h[j]))
    print("x \t\t y (Euler) \t y (analytical)")
    print("%f \t %f \t %f" % (x, y, f(x)))

    n = int((x_final - x) / h[j])

    x_n = np.zeros(n + 1)
    y_n = np.zeros(n + 1)
    x_n[0] = x
    y_n[0] = y

    for i in range(n):
        y += dy(x, y) * h[j]
        x += h[j]
        print("%f \t %f \t %f" % (x, y, f(x)))
        x_n[i + 1] = x
        y_n[i + 1] = y

    plt.plot(x_n, y_n, "x-", label="h=" + str(h[j]))


plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This plots the following on my computer:
[image: Euler Plot]

Note that I renamed your variable `xn` to `x_final` to avoid name confusion with the variables I introduced. As stated before, you need to store each of your x and y values in a container. I used NumPy arrays for that, but you can also use a list. This

```py
n = int((x_final - x) / h[j])

x_n = np.zeros(n + 1)
y_n = np.zeros(n + 1)
x_n[0] = x
y_n[0] = y
```

just creates 2 arrays of zeros with their size being equal to the number of substeps +1. Then I set the first values to be equal to the initial values. This must be inside the loop over `h` since the number of substeps `n` is different for each h.

At the end of your `i`-loop, I just write the current `x` and `y` values to the correct position in the arrays.

```py
for i in range(n):
    y += dy(x, y) * h[j]
    x += h[j]
    print("%f \t %f \t %f" % (x, y, f(x)))
    x_n[i + 1] = x
    y_n[i + 1] = y
```

Instead of calling `plt.plot` with `x` and `y`, which just plots a single point since they are sclars, you need to pass the arrays to the function:

```py
plt.plot(x_n, y_n, "x-", label="h=" + str(h[j]))
```

I also added a label that will show up in the legend and changed the line type to `"x-"`.

One mistake you made, that caused your `i` loop to be executed only for the first `h` was that you did not reset `x` and `y` to their initial values. So your `n` was always `0` after the first run of the outer loop.

There are certainly several things you can optimize, like using something like

```py
for h in h_list:
   ...
```

which would be a little bit more readable than always using `h[j]` instead of just `h`, but I think for now this is enough. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have done correct but their is glitch. Instead of yn+1 the y Euler u have printed the yn for different values of n.As per your code are writing y eulers which is actually yn.
So a suggestion from my side you can make this table like this xn , yn ,slope , yn+1 then the analytical ones.
Rest your code is all perfect

Comment: Thanks @RavneetKaur , keep up the good work :)